# Complex functions with zero derivative at some point

Tags: complex-analysis

What special properties do holomorphic and meromorphic complex functions $f(z)$ have if their derivative $f'(z_0) = 0$ is zero at some point $z_0$?

Comment: It means that locally at $z_0$ the map $f$ is not conformal.

Comment: @Crostul, thank you for the reply. Is it the only property? Is it valid only for holomorphic functions?

Comment: It's better to say what property has missed when $f'(z_0)=0$

Comment: $f$ has a neighbourhood where it is NOT injective.